# How to compare text from external .txt file to a string

Tags: java, string, if-statement, filereader, filewriter

I have achieved returning the text from external text file by using this method here

```
FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\boung\\Desktop\\usernames.txt");

int character;

while ((character = reader.read()) != -1) {
System.out.print((char) character);
}
reader.close();
```

This method prints

> username1

But now what I want to do is, I want to take the text that was returned from the text file and compare it to a String that was already set in the program. Like this:

```
        String S = "username1";

        FileReader reader = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\boung\\Desktop\\usernames.txt");
        int character;

        while ((character = reader.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) character);
        }
        reader.close();

        if (character.contains(S)) {
        System.out.println("username1 found");


    }
```

But I cant compare `character` and `S`.

I need to be able to stringify all of the text returned from the .txt file and check if the file contains a certain string im looking for. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read file not char-by-char but whole to one string
you can use next code

````
   String S = "username1";
   StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines( Paths.get("C:\\Users\\boung\\Desktop\\usernames.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
    {
        stream.forEach(s -> contentBuilder.append(s).append("\n"));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (contentBuilder.toString().contains(S)) {
        System.out.println("username1 found"); 
    }

    ```
````